# Access Singleton object in Flink subtasks

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, singleton, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a singleton class that is responsible for retrieving pooled connections. I was wondering what is the best way to access an object of this singleton class from Flink subtasks, since there is a potential issue of singleton object initialization in multithreaded environments. Is it best to lock the initialization of the singleton class using `synchronized` keyword or is there a better way to instantiate the singleton object in Flink runtime?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to use Singleton pattern with Flink at all, because multiple subtasks are computed on different machines (different slots). 
So if you want to work with the single state from all of machines you'd better keep this state in database and modify it within database transactions. If you just need one singleton object per flink slot (i.e. heavy objects like database connections) you could create it within open(...) method of RichFunction implementations